# How to exclude/include specific database columns when eager-loading a nested model in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

To keep things simple, I'll give an example in code to what I'm trying to Achieve.

Let's assume that we have a model called User with the following code:

```
class User 
{
   public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Post::class);
    }

}
```

And the Post model look something like this.

```
  class Post
    {
       public function comments()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
        }
    
    }
```

And now what I want to be able to do is for example:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$comments = $user->post->comments; //here, I only want the "comment_id" and "comment_content" fields to be included, not all the Comment Model fields !
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `hasManyThrough` in user model to connect comments table.

read about `hasManyThrough` here: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

and after having a relation between `user` and `comments` (hasManyThrough)

you can use `load` (Lazy eager loading) method

there is an piece of code you can use here

```
 $user->load(["comments" => function($q){
        $q->select("comment_id","comment_content");
 }]);
```

read more about Lazy eager loading: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)